# Why doesn't model save my data after submitting a form?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

My **Spring MVC** project is kind of a transaction service where you have Clients and list of Transactions. I am using Hibernate as well. I have this client panel in which client sees his balance, previous transactions and is able to to do new transactions. Here is a snippet of my **.jsp** file

Transfer Data is being passed just fine, but "loggedClient" attribute appears as an empty object with *nulls* getting passed as values. This only happens after clicking the **Submit** button and doesn't happen when refreshing the site. The key to solving thi problem may be the loggedClint.toString() which returns:
`Client [id=0, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=null, balance=0]`
Any Ideas why this is happening? How can I fix this so after submitting the transaction my "loggedClient" attribute stays filled with client's data ?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Welcome ${loggedClient.firstName} ${loggedClient.lastName}</h2>

    </div>
    <header><label class="balancelabel" > Balance: ${loggedClient.balance} </label></header>
</div>
<br><br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Transfer Money</legend>
            <form:form action="transferMoney" modelAttribute="transferData" >
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Recipients Email:</label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="mail" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Amount :</label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="amount" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label></label></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Send Transfer" class="save" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>        
                </table>
            </form:form>
    </fieldset><div id="container">

    <div id="content">

        <table>

            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Amount</th>     
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <!-- <th></th> -->
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="tempTransfer" items="${transferList}">

                <tr>
                    <td>${tempTransfer.sender.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${tempTransfer.receiver.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${tempTransfer.amount}</td>
                    <td>${tempTransfer.timestamp}</td>


                </tr>

            </c:forEach>

        </table>

    </div>
```

And here is the Controller code snippet:

```
@PostMapping("/transferMoney")
public String processTransfer(@ModelAttribute("loggedClient") Client loggedClient, @ModelAttribute("transferData") TransferDataContainer transferData, Model model) {

    Client recipient = clientService.getClient(transferData.getMail());
    System.out.println(loggedClient.toString());
    if(transferData.getAmount() > loggedClient.getBalance()) {
        System.out.println("You cannot send more than you have");
        //System.out.println("You were trying to send : " + transferData.getAmount() +" but you have " +  loggedClient.getBalance());
    } else if(recipient==null) {
        System.out.println("Invalid recepient");
    } else {
        int amount = transferData.getAmount();
        // Updating data
        loggedClient.setBalance(loggedClient.getBalance()-amount);
        recipient.setBalance(recipient.getBalance()+amount);
        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(amount, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) , loggedClient, recipient);

        clientService.saveClient(loggedClient);
        clientService.saveClient(recipient);
        transferService.saveTransfer(transfer);

    }
    return "client-logged";
```

}

Comment: Your code isn't changing any state on loggedClient.  It comes into the method, and you're logging it.  We need more code, or you need to do something with your recipient variable.

Comment: @jasonArmstrong I forgot to add that at the end of controller method I am retrurning the same **.jsp** file from which the method is invoked. And there is much more code getting processing the transaction but i chose not to add it (that's what the `...` meant). My biggest concern is why loggedClient.toString() gives the result of : `Client [id=0, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=null, balance=0]` It seems that it used a default constructor to create a new Client object while not using the one I've already saved in the model.

Comment: You need to add more code to the question so we can see how you're doing it; please post the entire method. There's nothing that you've described which is mutating state on `loggedClient`.  If you don't mutate state or reassign the arg, it's not going to change.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong here is the entire code

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see the problem now. What's happening is the loggedClient in your JSP is not within the form, so when the form is submitted only things in transferData are being sent.  If you want to send the loggedClient pieces back, you'll need to fold it in as hidden input fields within transferData.

For example, in your JSP:

```
<form...>
    <form:hidden path="loggedClient.firstName" value="${loggedClient.firstName"/> 
    <form:hidden path="loggedClient.lastName" value="${loggedClient.lastName"/>
...
</form>
```

Then in your control, remove the loggedClient parameter.  Update your TransferData class to include a loggedClient property, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did what you've proposed but I've encountered a bizarre problem. I've moved loggedClient to TransferData and it displays client name, balance etc fine. The list wasn't displaying well so I did the same thing: set transferList as a propery of Transferdata class and updated the <form:hidden ... > code to include transferList. When I did this i got _http status 400_ and caused by an exception: _ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.janchabik.banking.entity.Transfer' for property 'transferList[0]'_

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to include an entire object in the transfer and not just simple data. You can't include complex data/graphs in a hidden field. Sounds like you may be trying to transfer too much state from the client to the server. I recommend at this point going through some of the tutorials on Spring MVC and then come back to your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your form has only one modelAttribute.
When you submit the form only one object is passed, which is transferData. You will forever get the other one null due to the fact that loggedClient is not part of the form.

Anyway even if you will try to pass the loggedClient as form input parameters it won't populate the @ModelAttribute Client, cause the form has already a modelAttribute which is saying "transferData" and you can not add another one there.

If you want to pass the loggedClient information you have to change approach.
I suggest to use session for loggedClients and to not pass it page by page with forms.

In case session is not a solution for you and you must use @ModelAttribute you than have to consider to add inside transferData the fields of loggedClient and add them in the form as input parameters (quite bad design to be honest so I dont suggest this)